# How to identify call stack for dynamic loading of JavaScript files in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium with ChromeDriver through Python to load a webpage.

If a page loads a JavaScript file `a.js` which dynamically loads another JavaScript file `b.js` to the page, how can I find the "call stack" for each respective script tag?

#### Example:

I have a page `test.html` which loads `a.js`

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="a.js"></script>
</head>
</html>
```

`a.js` in turn loads `b.js`:

```
// a.js
s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = 'b.js';
document.head.appendChild(s);
```

If I load this page through Selenium the scripts will both be loaded and execute as expected. This can be seen by running

```
with Chrome() as driver:
  driver.get("http://localhost/test.html")
  script_tags = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("script")
  for s in script_tags:
    print(s.src)
```

This gives the output

```
http://localhost/a.js
http://localhost/b.js
```

Is there any way to tell how each respective script was loaded to the page?

In the example above, I would like to know that `a.js` was loaded directly through the page's HTML source and `b.js` was loaded by `a.js`.

Comment: Unless you parse and execute HTML and JavaScript, I would have no idea what to suggest. This is a *much* bigger problem than you realize. Can you add more about why you want to detect this?

Comment: This is part of an analysis performed against a large number of internal assets, some of which have loads of different dependencies. When an "unsanctioned" script is identified, the goal is to determine which other script is responsible for dynamically pulling it in.

Comment: In Chrome, call stacks can be viewed manually through Developer Tools, by hovering the `Initiator` column for a script under the Network tab.

Comment: I wonder if you can send the "F12" keys to open the developer console, and then automate interactions with the dev console to poke around the Network tab? I haven't done something like that before, but might be worth some googling.

Comment: Automating input to navigate the UI sounds both fragile and unfeasible, as this analysis is performed regularly from different machines where browser configuration and version may vary. The browser is also run in headless mode.

Any ideas regarding direct access to the call stack through Selenium/ChromeDriver would be helpful.